# android.support.v4.content.FileProvider not found

Tags: java, android, android-fileprovider

I am trying to upgrade a working old app to support Android API 26, and one of the thing I need to use is android.support.v4.content.FileProvider - but it was not found.

```
    <provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.fileprovider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
    </provider>
```

Due to the early Android build, the gradle file seems simple. Is it as simple as adding a dependency? I have look around and some suggested adding a multidex which I don't understand. Any help is appreciated, thank you!

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "virtualgs.spaint"
        minSdkVersion 22
        targetSdkVersion 26
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

add `compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'` to *build.gradle* file in app module.

Comment: I had same issue and resolved with implementation "com.android.support:support-core-utils:28.0.0"

Comment: Thank you so much! This is truly the answer. SOME OF US CANT USE API 28+ >.> other posters!

Answer (score 179):

As of AndroidX (the repackaged Android Support Library), the path is `androidx.core.content.FileProvider` so the updated provider tag would be:

```
<provider
    android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
    android:authorities="${applicationId}.fileprovider"
    android:exported="false"
    android:grantUriPermissions="true">
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
        android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
</provider>
```

Android Support Libraries are now in the  `androidx.*` package hierarchy.

`android.*` is now reserved to the built-in Android System Libraries.

Comment: Thanks! Did know that but did not realize that

Comment: Just a heads-up, as of Oct 2019, the meta-data flag is still the same "android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS". Refer to question https://stackoverflow.com/q/53390060/1303595 for ongoing updates.

Comment: This should be the accepted solution as per documentation:

(Deprecated)
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider

(New location) 
https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate/class-mappings

Comment: hi, i tried this android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider" to get the Uri from intent of image pick from photos. I geti this uri  /1/1/content:/media/external/images/media/183104/ORIGINAL/NONE/image/jpeg/1888135492:  getting file not found exception using file provider if not using getting security exception. Please help.

Comment: This is the must updated answer, it should appear right after the question.

Answer (score 57):

Instead of

```
import android.support.v4.content.FileProvider;
```

Try importing

```
import androidx.core.content.FileProvider;
```

Comment: This helped me in resolving the gradle error in Android Studio 3.6

Comment: This helped with Ionic 5 and Capacitor

Comment: @HoussemBadri if i rebuild my project i have to change it again, any suggestions?

Comment: @oldmayn, me too, I'm still rechanging it each time

Comment: @HoussemBadri as [suggested by ionic](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/android/updating) you could use [jetifier](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jetifier)

Comment: in ionic 4+ instead of import,  full name is used. `class someClassName extends androidx.core.content.FileProvider` Do not miss this.

Comment: this answer works perfectly for a capacitor using Cordova plugin. ..

Comment: @oldmayn i i also have to change it each time i build. did you find a solution to keep this change permanent?

Answer (score 26):

Using the following commands solved my issue:

```
npm install jetifier --save-dev
npx jetify
npx cap sync
```

Answer (score 15):

I replaced it with the newer version, which is : androidx.core.content.FileProvider

This worked for me.

Answer (score 14):

Change to

```
public class FileProvider extends androidx.core.content.FileProvider {
}
```

Answer (score 8):

for androidx

```
<provider
    android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
    android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
    android:exported="false"
    android:grantUriPermissions="true">
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
        android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
</provider>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create your class

```
import android.support.v4.content.FileProvider;

public class GenericFileProvider extends FileProvider {
}
```

Add this provider into your AndroidManifest.xml under application tag:

```
<provider
      android:name=".utilities.GenericFileProvider"
      android:authorities="${applicationId}.utilities.GenericFileProvider"
      android:exported="false"
      android:grantUriPermissions="true">
         <meta-data
             android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
             android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
</provider>
```

Comment: I thought the whole issue is "android.support.v4.content.FileProvider" cannot be found?

Comment: Creating empty classes is useless.

Answer (score 0):

Ionic users,

```
ionic cordova rm android
```

Do that and then rebuild your app.

Answer (score 0):

If you are having this issue with multiple dependencies, you can migrate your entire project to Android X.

To do this, right-click the "app" folder in your project, select "Refactor" and then "Migrate to Android X".

Here's a pic:

[Dialog Menu to migrate Android X Project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rIXGh.png)