# Migrating to AndroidX - android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS location

Tags: android, androidx

I am in the middle of migrating a project to AndroidX and I am blocked with an issue.

```
<provider
    android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider" <--- Changed to X lib
    android:authorities="${applicationId}.fileprovider"
    android:exported="false"
    android:grantUriPermissions="true">
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS" <---- ISSUE
        android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
</provider>
```

I searched all the Internet and couldn't find a solution for this: what should I add instead of android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS for AndroidX?

Comment: It looks to be still the same – https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-master-dev/core/src/main/java/androidx/core/content/FileProvider.java#343. What problems are you having?

Comment: You are right. I had no issue, but I wanted to be sure that this won't crash at some point and because I saw the "support" keyword there, I thought that Android Studio didn't do the migration right (for example, for the android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView it didn't work. I had to do it manually.) Thanks for the answer!

Comment: could you please show the method where you are fetching the image.

Comment: Up to now, the `FileProvider` class from `AndroidX` package has a final static string variable called `META_DATA_FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS` which references the old string used on the support library: `"android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"`. Therefore I guess it's ok to use it the xml file.

Comment: In android manifest it is already like that (androidx.core.content.FileProvider), but in fileprovider.java file it is different android.support.v4.content.FileProvider => Always I need to change this manually to take a android build

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Still the same. `android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS` is in the example [here](https://developer.android.com/training/secure-file-sharing/setup-sharing)

Answer (score 16):

```
<provider
    android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
    android:authorities="com.mydomain.fileprovider"
    android:exported="false"
    android:grantUriPermissions="true">
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
        android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
</provider>
```

For androidx, the metadata should be like this. Checkout this from android studio : https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/content/FileProvider.html