# MAUI Android 10 install APK programmatically

Tags: c#, android, apk, maui

I am trying to install an .apk I have downloaded to the downloads folder in Android 10.
I have tried this [Xamarin Android 7+ install APK programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45014498/xamarin-android-7-install-apk-programmatically).

I gote this error:

> Java.Lang.RuntimeException: 'Unable to get provider
> android.support.v4.content.FileProvider:
> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
> "android.support.v4.content.FileProvider" on path: DexPathList[[zip
> file
> "/data/app/{PackName}-aV7Nkryw8OSTkpHc_8WmMg==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/{PackName}-aV7Nkryw8OSTkpHc_8WmMg==/lib/arm64,
> /data/app/{PackName}-aV7Nkryw8OSTkpHc_8WmMg==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a,
> /system/lib64, /product/lib64]]'

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="{PackName}">
    <application android:allowBackup="true" android:icon="@mipmap/appicon" android:roundIcon="@mipmap/appicon_round" android:supportsRtl="true" android:label="{Label}">
        <provider android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider" android:authorities="{PackName}.provider" android:exported="false" android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS" android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
        </provider>
    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES" />
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="24"/>
</manifest>
```

provider_paths.xml

```
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <external-path name="external_files" path="." />  
</paths>
```

Code:

```
Context context = AndroidApp.Context;
var file = new Java.IO.File(fileUri);
if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.N)
{
    var apkUri = FileProvider.GetUriForFile(context, context.ApplicationContext.PackageName + ".provider", file);
    Intent intentS = new Intent(Intent.ActionInstallPackage);
    intentS.SetData(apkUri);
    intentS.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.GrantReadUriPermission);
    context.StartActivity(intentS);
}
```

Comment: `android.support.v4` is the package name of the old deprecated Android support library which has been replaced with `androidx`. If you use AndroidX library in your project please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48534293/android-support-v4-content-fileprovider-not-found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your target framework  is set to Android 10 or later, and you are still using the old package, so you can try to change `android.support.v4.FileProvider` to `androidx.core.content.FileProvider`.

You can refer to the following code:

```
<provider android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider" android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider" android:exported="false" android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS" android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
</provider>
```